# Как форматировать данные в JTable

Tags: java

Есть таблица, код который прописан ниже описан в другом классе (на заметку).Таблица должна иметь 1 колонку, и 14 рядков. У меня есть отформатированный массив стрингов, который имеет только одно значения (с[0]).

```
private int columnCount = 1;
//private int rowCount = 14;
private ArrayList<String []> data;

public JTBModel() {
    data = new ArrayList<String []>();
    for (int i = 0;  i < data.size(); i++){
        data.add(new String [getColumnCount()]);
    }
}

public int getColumnCount() {

    return columnCount;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex){
    switch (columnIndex){
    case 0: return "Валюта       ||      Купівля       || Продажа || Комерція";

    }
    return "";
}




public int getRowCount() {

    return data.size();
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    String [] rows =  data.get(rowIndex);

    return rows[columnIndex];
}

public void addData(String [] row){
    String [] rowTable = new String[14];
    rowTable = row;
    data.add(rowTable);
}
```

Вот этот массив является отформатированным, все эти значения находятся в с[0],
как мне вывести эти значения что бы была одна колонка, название было (Валюта || Купівля || Продажа || Комерція), а данные в ней йшли так как показано ниже, не могу разобратся, посмотрите код, может я где то что то забыл, или же тупо не написал.Подскажите что то.

```
USD || 28.082 -0.050 || 27.761 -0.033 || 28.0195 27.930020
EUR || 32.607 -0.090 || 31.970 -0.085 || 32.3292 32.362514
RUB || 0.436 +0.003  || 0.372 +0.004  || 0.4288 0.426210
GBP || 37.380 -0.066 || 35.676 -0.088 || 36.8098 36.946462
CHF || 28.560 -0.092 || 27.101 -0.130 || 28.2307 28.279023
PLN || 7.638 +0.015  || 7.083 +0.050  || 7.5686 7.545468
JPY || 0.251         || 0.239 +0.001  || 0.2497 0.249096
CAD || 21.950 +0.265 || 20.450 +0.800 || 21.5661 21.560636
AUD || 20.330 +0.030 || 19.500 +0.070 || 19.9768 19.923976
DKK || 4.370         || 4.100         || 4.3496 4.337615
NOK || 3.460 +0.020  || 3.280         || 3.4203 3.435584
SEK || 3.160 +0.010  || 2.970         || 3.1315 3.136966
CZK || 1.297         || 1.193         || 1.2570 1.253341
HUF || 0.104 +0.001  || 0.091         || 0.1008 0.100486
```

Comment: Похоже на попытку запрягать собак в автомобиль, как в старом анекдоте. Почему бы просто не выводить 4 колонки?

Comment: @Hivemaster то есть? Не понял вас

Comment: @Hivemaster а как вывести 4 колонки если у меня массив из одного индекса

Comment: Формируйте двумерный массив, а лучше сразу TableModel.

Comment: @Hivemaster я не понимаю что и как делать, можете как то помочь?